# Bundle multiple JavaScript files and access class defined in bundle: what technology to use, and how?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, browserify

I'm new to JavaScript and its technologies for bundling modules for use in the browser, i.e. Browserify, Webpack, etc. So please bear with me:

Say I have three JavaScript files, each which defines a class:

`file1.js`:

```
class MyClass1 {
   constructor() {
     ...
   }
   ...

}
```

`file2.js`:

```
class MyClass2 {
   constructor() {
     ...
   }
   ...

}
```

Now in the third file, `main.js`, I want to use the classes defined in the other two files, like so:

```
class MainClass {
   constructor() {
     this.myClass1 = new MyClass1;
     this.myClass2 = new MyClass2;
   }
   ...


}
```

And in the end I want to import the `main.js` script in my HTML file with a simple script tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<head>
    <script src="../main.js"></script>
</head>
...
<script>
   let mainClass = new MainClass();
   // call some methods on the mainClass object
</script>
```

Now, what is the best way to accomplish this modularization of my code?

I was able to make it work with Browserify with `require` syntax and then put `window.MainClass = MainClass` at the end of `main.js`.

However, this might not be the cleanest solution. I'm looking advice as to how to go about bundling up the files in this case. :)

Comment: Regardless of what approach at bundling you use, the accepted and cleanest solution is to use ES6 module syntax in the source files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that you have a folder that will be used for deployment, like `/dist` , `/public` where that html file is.

With `wepback` , you could put all of the files under `/src` and execute,

```
   webpack src/main.js -o dist/main.js // you will need webpack cli installed on your machine
```

This will look at `src/main.js` as an entry point and bundle files to `dist/main.js`.

For that command to run successfully, you will need to modify how those classes are exported/imported. Imports can be written like so,

```
//main.js 
import MyClass1 from 'src/file1'
```

and exports can be written like so,

```
//file1.js
export default class MyClass1 { ... }
```

And run the webpack command, you should be able to write what you wanted to inside the `<script>`tag.

Note: You can probably write import/export just by installing webpack. However, if you want to write the app in ES6, you will need to install other dependencies.

```
Version 2 of webpack supports ES6 module syntax natively, meaning you can use import and export without a tool like babel to handle this for you. Keep in mind that you will still probably need babel for other ES6+ features.
```